# develop android multiplayer game

Tags: android, multiplayer

I try to develop a multiplayer game in android,so far I developed the game on client side and it works fine,but now I got to know how I develop the server side.
How people can play in the internet?
The game is turns base,all I need to know is what to start with,I have read some articles about it but I can't understand if I need to pruchase a server and how to connect the server via android.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server API for multiplayer game,

for example 1st player moved to position 25.

send a post request to http://example.com/move with some parameters(like postion,etc)

and other side he can continuously check for move

use PHP,MySql,Slim frame work to make an API.

i found an tutorial for you http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Comment: Thanks!
I know asp.net,and I never used PHP is it nessacry to learn?

Comment: No, you can make an api using asp.net.

Comment: @Zachinio if you plan to make a multiplayer game, I strongly suggest to use PHP on a LINUX machine, because a windows server will be more hackable and slower...

Answer (score 0):

If you are distributing your game only through Google Play you can use Google Play Games Services to develop multiplayer games without the need for a server.

Check here for more details https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

It's simple and easy to get started.

Comment: "Support for real-time and turn-based multiplayer APIs ended on March 31st, 2020" https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9469745